# How to choose a paragraph an change its style with InDesign script

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe-indesign

I am parsing a XML document into InDesign and than trying to change every paragraph's style.

If I do it like this:

```
myTextFrame.parentStory.texts.item(0).applyParagraphStyle(<<style>>);
```

it will change the whole text as it would be a single paragraph.

This code, however, won't work at all:

```
for (var i = 0; i < <<paragraphs.length>>; i++)
{
    if (styles[i].isValid)
        myTextFrame.parentStory.texts.item(i).applyParagraphStyle(styles[i]);
}
```

Also it seems that I can't call the 'applyParagraphStyle' method on 'Paragraph' class.

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
   <book>
      <authors>
         <author>Lee Roy</author>    
      </authors>
      <title>Name of the book</title>
      <subtitle>How to XML</subtitle>
   </book>
</root>
```

Then i parse them like this:

```
var string = "";
for (var i = 0; i < wholeXML.length(); i++)
{
    var book = wholeXML.child(i);

    string += book.child("title").toString() + "\r";
    string += book.child("subtitle").toString() + "\r";
}
```

The output would look like something like this:

```
Name of the book
How to XML
```

Now, my question is: How can I change a single paragraph's style?

Comment: `applyParagraphStyle` *is a method on the `Paragraph` class*, so I would look closely at why your second code block above doesn't work. Either the arguments you're passing in are bad, or `myTextFrame.parentStory.texts.item(i)` is returning something that *isn't a paragraph*. Time to fire up the debugger and step through, examining everything up to the crash.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the paragraph style of a single paragraph by setting its `appliedParagraphStyle` property.

```
myTextFrame.parentStory.paragraphs[0].appliedParagraphStyle = "nameOfParagraphStyle";
```